# Why aren't comments to my question being answered?

Tags: soporte, comentarios

At [Consonants combined with an "h" and double consonants](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/35036/consonants-combined-with-an-h-and-double-consonants), I have been asking where do "valley" and "valle" come from, and no one has been replying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you've tried to ping one of the users who wrote an answer with [a comment on your question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/35036/consonants-combined-with-an-h-and-double-consonants#comment62854_35036), but it doesn't work that way; see [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/295232). They did get a notification from [this comment under their answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/35036/consonants-combined-with-an-h-and-double-consonants#comment62844_35044).

Second, please remember that we're volunteers here; we're not *required* to answer questions. The user has been online after the notification (you can see that in [their profile](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/14627/pablodf76)) but they might have had little time.